# Why is my Target not executed?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-target

I have the following Targets file that is imported into my `.csproj` file, One of the targets (AfterAddPostAction) never fires. Why not?
(Sorry it's so verbose but MSBuild is shit at abstraction and CallTask doesn't see Property values set inside the Target containing the CallTask element.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>

<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="EstablishLog">
    <MakeDir Condition="!Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Logs')" Directories=".\Logs"/>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <PowerShellExe Condition=" '$(PowerShellExe)'=='' ">%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</PowerShellExe>
      <ScriptPath Condition=" '$(ScriptPath)'=='' ">C:\Users\Admin\Documents\GitHub\powershell-scripts\</ScriptPath>
      <LogState>$(ScriptPath)ProjectSnapShot.ps1</LogState>
      <DoPostAction>$(ScriptPath)postAction-BeforePublish.ps1</DoPostAction>
      <Switches>-NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted</Switches>
      <Arguments>&quot;&amp; { &amp;&apos;$(ScriptPath)&apos; } &quot;</Arguments>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="AfterClean" DependsOnTargets="EstablishLog">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <LogFile >AfterClean$(ApplicationVersion).log</LogFile>
      <LogFile Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Logs')">.\Logs\$(LogFile)</LogFile>
      <Arguments>&quot;&amp; { &amp;&apos;$(LogState)&apos; } &quot;</Arguments>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) $(Switches) -command $(Arguments) &gt; $(LogFile)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild" DependsOnTargets="EstablishLog">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <LogFile >BeforeBuild$(ApplicationVersion).log</LogFile>
      <LogFile Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Logs')">.\Logs\$(LogFile)</LogFile>
      <Arguments>&quot;&amp; { &amp;&apos;$(LogState)&apos; } &quot;</Arguments>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) $(Switches) -command $(Arguments) &gt; $(LogFile)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="EstablishLog">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <LogFile >AfterBuild$(ApplicationVersion).log</LogFile>
      <LogFile Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Logs')">.\Logs\$(LogFile)</LogFile>
      <Arguments>&quot;&amp; { &amp;&apos;$(LogState)&apos; } &quot;</Arguments>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) $(Switches) -command $(Arguments) &gt; $(LogFile)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="BeforePublish" DependsOnTargets="EstablishLog">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <LogFile >BeforePublish$(ApplicationVersion).log</LogFile>
      <LogFile Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Logs')">.\Logs\$(LogFile)</LogFile>
      <Arguments>&quot;&amp; { &amp;&apos;$(LogState)&apos; } &quot;</Arguments>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) $(Switches) -command $(Arguments) &gt; $(LogFile)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="AddPostAction" AfterTargets="BeforePublish" DependsOnTargets="EstablishLog">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <PostAction>FileCopyPDA.FileCopyPDA</PostAction>
      <Arguments>&quot;&amp; { &amp;&apos;$(DoPostAction)&apos; &apos;$(PostAction)&apos; $(Configuration)} &quot;</Arguments>
      <LogFile >AddPostAction$(ApplicationVersion).log</LogFile>
      <LogFile Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Logs')">.\Logs\$(LogFile)</LogFile>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) $(Switches) -command $(Arguments) &gt; $(LogFile)" />
  </Target>

  <!--This one is never called-->
  <Target Name="AfterAddPostAction" DependsOnTargets="EstablishLog;AddPostAction">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <LogFile >AfterAddPostAction$(ApplicationVersion).log</LogFile>
      <LogFile Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Logs')">.\Logs\$(LogFile)</LogFile>
      <Arguments>&quot;&amp; { &amp;&apos;$(LogState)&apos; } &quot;</Arguments>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) $(Switches) -command $(Arguments) &gt; $(LogFile)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="AfterPublish" DependsOnTargets="EstablishLog">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <LogFile >AfterPublish$(ApplicationVersion).log</LogFile>
      <LogFile Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Logs')">.\Logs\$(LogFile)</LogFile>
      <Arguments>&quot;&amp; { &amp;&apos;$(LogState)&apos; } &quot;</Arguments>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) $(Switches) -command $(Arguments) &gt; $(LogFile)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: What is in the msbuild log file when log level is set to detailed or diagnostics?

Comment: I had it set to Diagnostic actually and no mention of `AfterAddPostAction`.  Not even to skip .  What I discovered was that `DependsOnTargets` is not sufficient but `AfterTargets` is.  I still don't understand why.

Comment: And which target you are executing as a 'primary' target? Right now I see dozen of targets and it is not clear how they are invoked.

Comment: Hi @IgorLabutin, you are right.  The main problem was that I was not understanding how the tasks are chained.  After I realised to use `AfterTargets` to establish the sequence I was OK.

Comment: `DependsOnTargets` is the primary way to chain tasks into the sequence. But if you have sequence `A->B->C` implemented via `DependsOnTargets` (B depends on A) and call target `A` externally, then B and C will not be executed. But if you call C, then both A and B are executed.

Comment: Thanks @IgorLabutin, if you want to put that in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DependsOnTargets` is the primary way to chain tasks into the sequence. But if you have sequence `A->B->C` implemented via `DependsOnTargets` (`B` depends on `A`) and call target `A`, then `B` and `C` will not be executed. But if you call `C`, then both `A` and `B` are executed.

On the contrary the target that has target `A` mentioned in `AfterTargets` attribute will be executed after `A` is executed.

That's why in your case if you want to use `DependsOnTargets` it is important which target you execute.